# PostgreSQL: преобразовать значения пар json-а для вставки в запрос в функции

Tags: postgresql

Прошу помощи. Моя PostgreSQL функция принимает параметром json

```
my_json = {"0":"a1", "1":"a2", "2":"a3"}
```

Как логически и синтаксически грамотно вытащить внутри моей функции значения каждой пары для вставки в запрос

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE value IN ('a1', 'a2', 'a3');
```

Comment: функция на каком языке хоть?

Comment: LANGUAGE plpgsql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним запросом можно как-то так:

```
DELETE FROM my_table 
  WHERE value IN (SELECT value FROM json_each_text('{"0":"a1", "1":"a2", "2":"a3"}'));
```

ИМХО функция тут будет избыточна, но если нужна ради инкапсуляции, то как-то так:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JsonGetVals(jdoc json) 
  RETURNS setof text 
  AS 'SELECT value FROM json_each_text(jdoc)' 
  LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

Использование:

```
DELETE FROM my_table 
  WHERE value IN (SELECT JsonGetVals('{"0":"a1", "1":"a2", "2":"a3"}'));
```

Если угодно именно на PL/pgSQL, то изменения будут тривиальны.

Comment: огромное спасибо! то что надо!

Comment: я разобрался. еще раз спасибо большое!